# Set Max erros while uploading data from bucket using R

Tags: r, google-bigquery

Im bigrquery to upload data from google bucket to bigquery and i like to set the maximum number of errors i will allow (default is 0 )

for that im using bq_perform_load

```
bq_job<-    
  bq_perform_load(bq_table(destination_project,destination_dataset,destination_table_temp),
                  file_name,
                  source_format ="CSV",
                  nskip="1",
                  create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                  write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                  fields = bq_fields,         
                  billing = destination_project)
```

as part of the documentation it looks like there is an ability to add additional arguments

...
Additional arguments passed on to the underlying API call. snake_case names are automatically converted to camelCase.

but im not sure how to use it

ive tried something like that

```
bq_perform_load(bq_table(destination_project,destination_dataset,destination_table_temp),
                  file_name,
                  source_format ="CSV",
                  nskip="1",
                  create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                  write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                  fields = bq_fields,
                  maxBadRecords = "500",
                  billing = destination_project)
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Try with max_bad_records instead

Comment: i've tried that its not working, according to documentation its convert the name convention to the right format